# CSS layout two columns with indent in second column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to do this layout without breaking it into two separate wrapper columns. It should be one list of divs.
But the second column should start with a margin-top or indent.

[sample photo](https://i.ibb.co/Kbv09SW/Screenshot-2019-08-19-16-08-27.png)

At the moment I've done 2 columns inside of the wrapper, but that means that items in the second column will be pushed after the first column in mobile. Don't want that.

The code should be like:

```
<div class="items-wrapper">
<div class="item">foo</div>
<div class="item">foo</div>
<div class="item">foo</div>
<div class="item">foo</div>
</div>
```

EDIT:
I tried to do like this: 
https://codepen.io/wackou/pen/pozEybR

Perhaps there's better way?

Comment: Post the full HTML and CSS you've tried that illustrates the problem. We can help you more efficiently if we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/wackou/pen/pozEybR

Comment: instead margin, you may use transform : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/jONMqaB and simplify sizing via min-width  + flex. or column-count ?  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/VwZKaxJ to keep your negative margin idea .

Comment: OK, I guess your code is better and probably can't get much simpler anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give to the "items-wrapper" class a flex property and next change the flex direction to column